# XSLT: how to count preceding sibling, excluding certain node types?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to write a template rule, where the match attribute use preceding-sibling operator excluding certain types of nodes?
I try to explain my self. I have this xml input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <graph>
   <vertex name="A"/>
   <edge name="AB" />
   <tag name="tagA"/>
   <vertex name="C"/>
   <edge name="AB"/>
   <vertex name="AA"/>
   <edge name="AAD"/>
   <vertex name="D"/>
   <vertex name="AAA"/>
   <tag name="tagE"/>
   <vertex name="E"/>
  </graph>
```

What I want to extract is a `vertex` whose preceding-sibling excluding all the nodes of type tag, is a `vertex` with `name` containing `A` char. In this case, the output I desire is:
    `<vertex name="E"/>`

I don't know which `template` rule I should write, because I know how to set a constraint for the first preceding sibling of a given type:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:template match="vertex[preceding-sibling::vertex[1]
    [self::vertex[contains(@name, 'A')]]]">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
```

I am able to write a match for the first `preceding-sibling` of a node, without specifying any type, but it does not help me in this situation.
The problem here is I would like to tell to XSLT to consider all preceding sibling, but not the one of type `tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the match expression you want is this...

```
 <xsl:template match="vertex[preceding-sibling::*[not(self::tag)][1][self::vertex[contains(@name, 'A')]]]">
```

Doing `preceding-sibling::vertex[1]` will find the first `vertex` that precedes the current node, which might not be the most immediately preceding sibling. Doing `preceding-sibling::*[not(self::tag)][1]` will get the most preceding sibling that is not a `tag`, which you can then check to be a `vertex`.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not what I am looking for, because I want the immediately preceding sibling, unless this is a `tag`. I have edited my example to be more clear. I still desire to receive as output `<vertex name="E"/>` even if its most preceding sibling is a `tag`. This because I would like to set constraint on the most preceding sibling that is not a `tag`.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer, to take `tag` records into account.